# Conditionally selecting top 1 from groups based on cascading conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select the "top 1" record from each group of items based on set of "cascading if conditions".

The grouping is based on the MovieId, Formatid, and Date.

Here's an example of my table (broken up a bit to highlight the 4 "cases" of the logic that I'm trying to implement)...

```
Id | MovieId | FormatId | SourceId | Date       | Lock | Created    | Modified
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1        | 1        | 2014-03-12 | 1    | 2014-03-12 | NULL
2  | 1       | 1        | 2        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
3  | 1       | 1        | 3        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | 2014-03-13
4  | 1       | 1        | 4        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL

5  | 1       | 2        | 1        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
6  | 1       | 2        | 2        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
7  | 1       | 2        | 3        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
8  | 1       | 2        | 4        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL

9  | 1       | 3        | 1        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
10 | 1       | 3        | 3        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | 2014-03-13

11 | 2       | 1        | 2        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
```

My expected results would be these rows...

```
1  | 1       | 1        | 1        | 2014-03-12 | 1    | 2014-03-12 | NULL
8  | 1       | 2        | 4        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
10 | 1       | 3        | 3        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | 2014-03-13
11 | 2       | 1        | 2        | 2014-03-12 | NULL | 2014-03-12 | NULL
```

So here's the algorithm (again, per MovieId/FormatId/Date group)...

First, If there is a record with SourceId = 1 AND Lock NOT NULL, Then pick that one.
Secondly, If there is a record with SourceId = 4, Then pick that one.
Third, If there are records where SourceId <> 2, Then pick the most recently updated one.
Finally, If there is ONLY 1 record where SourceId = 2, Then pick that one.

Two other notes/requests... 1) I already have an indexed view that does some of this and uses a "conditional ORDER BY" clause with ROW_NUMBER(), i.e.

> ORDER BY (CASE WHEN X THEN A END) DESC, (CASE WHEN Y THEN B END)...

but it's not entirely correct and the performance is HORRIBLE! 2) This table is quite large (currently about 6 million rows), so some of the things I've seen recommended work for small'ish tables, but this table isn't one of them.

Thanks in advance!
--Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is just saying:  "Use `row_number()`, Use `row_number()`!"

This assigns a sequential number to each row within a group.  The rows are ordered based on the `order by`.  For this, just use the logic for your priorities:

```
select Id, MovieId, FormatId, SourceId, Date, Lock, Created, Modified
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MovieId, FormatId, Date
                                order by (case when SourceId = 1 AND Lock NOT NULL then 1
                                               when SourceId = 4 then 2
                                               when SourceId <> 2 then 3
                                               when SourceId = 2 then 4
                                               else 5
                                          end), Modified desc
                               ) as seqnum,
            sum(case when SourceId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by MovieId, FormatId, Date) as NumSourceId2
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and not (SourceId = 2 and NumSourceId2 > 1);
```

Note that this will still select a row when none of the conditions are met.  You don't specify what to do in that case.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, thanks for the quick response, unfortunately I get a `"Column 'table.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."` error. But there is no "GROUP BY", so I'm not sure what it's complaining about?!?

Comment: @HenryC . . . That `sum()` should have been a window function, not an aggregation function.

Comment: Gordon thanks I thought that might be the issue. It's very close now! The only case that doesn't seem to work is the 3rd case where last modified takes precedence. So in my sample data, I would expect row 10 to be chosen over row 9. I tried putting `ISNULL(Modified, Created) DESC` instead of just `Modified DESC`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. I ran it against some of my real data and got the correct results, so I just ran it against the sample data that I provided, and it's giving me rows 1, 8, 10, and 11 as I was requesting. Let me look at a couple of more cases...

Comment: This did work, but for our table structure and number of records was just too slow to meet the needs of the customer, so I ended up pulling this logic up into the C# code where it operates on a much smaller subset of records, and is much faster than trying to do it in SQL. Again, this does work overall, just didn't end up working for our scenario. Thanks @Gordon